# StrComp returns false when two strings are different using VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access, string-comparison, false-positive

I'm trying to compare two string values in VBA but I've found a weird quirk of VBA ( or it seems so ). See Below:

If I do the following:

```
Debug.Print("Same" & StrComp(Me.txtFirstName.Value, Me.txtFirstName.Value, vbTextCompare))
Debug.Print("Different" & StrComp(Me.txtFirstName.Value, Me.txtFirstName.OldValue, vbTextCompare))
```

I get:

```
Same: 0
Different: 1
```

Which is something I would expect. However. If I then try to do the following:

```
Debug.Print("Same" & StrComp(Me.txtFirstName.Value, Me.txtFirstName.Value, vbTextCompare) = 0)
Debug.Print("Different" & StrComp(Me.txtFirstName.Value, Me.txtFirstName.OldValue, vbTextCompare) = 0)
```

I then get:

```
Same: False
Different: False
```

For reference, the values should be (for example)

```
Same test: "Jane", "Jane"
Different test: "Jane", "John"
```

Which is not what I expect. I know I'm doing something incorrectly but I'm not exactly sure what.

Any help is appreciated.

EDIT:

When I now enter this into an if statement:

```
If (StrComp(Me.txtFirstName.Value, Me.txtFirstName.OldValue, vbTextCompare) = 0) Then
    Debug.Print ("Hello")
Else
    Debug.Print ("Goodbye")
End If
```

I get a result of `Goodbye`

Comment: The code you have shown could not result in this output, it results in Error 13: Type mismatch because it's parsed as `("Same" & StrComp(s1, s2, vbTextCompare)) = 0`. Having fixed it to `"Same" & (StrComp(s1, s2, vbTextCompare) = 0)` you will get `SameTrue` rather than `Same: False`.

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is that it first concatentates `"Different" & StrComp(Me.txtFirstName.Value, Me.txtFirstName.OldValue` and then compares that with `=0`.

And `Different1` is not `0` therefore you get `False`.

use parenthesis to evaluate the comparison before concatenating:

```
Debug.Print("Same" & (StrComp(Me.txtFirstName.Value, Me.txtFirstName.Value, vbTextCompare) = 0))
Debug.Print("Different" & (StrComp(Me.txtFirstName.Value, Me.txtFirstName.OldValue, vbTextCompare) = 0))
```

---

Actually this code

```
Debug.Print("Same" & StrComp(Me.txtFirstName.Value, Me.txtFirstName.Value, vbTextCompare) = 0)
```

should have end up in a *Type Mismatch* error.

---

```
If StrComp(Me.txtFirstName.Value, Me.txtFirstName.Value, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
    MsgBox "They are the same"
Else
    MsgBox "They are different"
End If
```

Comment: Hi, how would I  be able to implement this into an if statement?

Comment: @JamieRhys see my edit